# "unable to dequeue a cell with identifier" when switching to programmatic transition instead of segue

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have 2 views, a main view with a button inside, and a table view. The table view cell has the identifier "ResultsTableViewCell". My goal is to make it so that when I press the button on the main view, I transition to the table view

When I use a storyboard segue, everything works fine. However, when I take out the segue and instead assign the button an action to make the transition programmatically, I get the error mentioned. Why is this?

Here is the code:

ViewController.swift (this is the only file I'm making any changes in)

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

/* How come this throws an unable to dequeue error but a segue works?
@IBAction func buttonMe(sender: UIButton) {
    let a = ResultsTableViewController()
    let b = self.navigationController
    b!.pushViewController(a, animated: true)
}
*/

}
```

ResultsTableViewController.swift

```
import UIKit
class ResultsTableViewController: UITableViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    // I found out the next line overwrites any cell customization and commented it out, so this isn't the problem
    //self.tableView.registerClass(ResultsTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "ResultsTableViewCell") 
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ResultsTableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ResultsTableViewCell
    cell.label1.text = "sUP"
    cell.label2.text = " heLLo"
    return cell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

}
```

ResultsTableViewCell.swift

```
import UIKit

class ResultsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var label1: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var label2: UILabel!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
}

}
```

If you're wondering why I don't just use a segue, there are 2 reasons:

1. I want to learn why this occurs
2. My real app transitions on a special case that I need to program in

I'm also dead certain that I set the cell identifier in storyboard. The segue wouldn't work otherwise. Lastly, both views are embedded in nav controllers already

Comment: `ResultsTableViewController()` is fishy. You should be getting it from the storyboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't creating the viewController correctly.  When you do this:

```
let a = ResultsTableViewController()
```

You get an instance of the class `ResultsTableViewController()`, but you don't get anything that was laid out in the *Storyboard*.  There is no connection from the code to the *Storyboard*.

Instead, you need to ask the *Storyboard* to instantiate the viewController:

```
if let a = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("resultsTable") as? ResultsTableViewController {
    // push a
}
```

In order for this to work, the *Storyboard ID* needs to be set in the *Identity Inspector*.

Comment: Thank you! I thought having the navigation controller push my created instance would connect it to the storyboard, but I guess the storyboard has to make the view in the first place

Answer (score 0):

// Assume ResultsTableViewControllerIdentifier is the identifier of ResultsTableViewController

```
 @IBAction func buttonMe(sender: UIButton) {

        let resultsTableViewControllerObj= self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ResultsTableViewControllerIdentifier") as? ResultsTableViewController


        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(resultsTableViewControllerObj!, animated: true)


        }
```